# transferring rdf to 4store

Tags: python, debian, sparql, 4store

actually I have a code named rdf.py that generates rdf code ..what I want to do is to directly move that file in 4store..                                                               I have stored the entire code in a variable and want to directly pass that variable to 4store.. is it possible?

the code of rdf.py is below.
rdf_code contains the entire rdf code that is generated

```
import rdflib
from rdflib.events import Dispatcher, Event
from rdflib.graph import ConjunctiveGraph as Graph
from rdflib import plugin
from rdflib.store import Store, NO_STORE, VALID_STORE
from rdflib.namespace import Namespace
from rdflib.term import Literal
from rdflib.term import URIRef
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from gstudio.models import *
from objectapp.models import *
from reversion.models import Version
from optparse import make_option

def get_nodetype(name):
    """
    returns the model the id belongs to.  
    """    
    try:
        """ 
        ALGO:     get object id, go to version model, return for the given id.
        """
        node = NID.objects.get(title=str(name))
        # Retrieving only the relevant tupleset for the versioned objects
        vrs = Version.objects.filter(type=0 , object_id=node.id) 
        # Returned value is a list, so splice it .
        vrs =  vrs[0]

    except Error:
        return "The item was not found."

    return vrs.object._meta.module_name   


def rdf_description(name, notation='xml' ):
    """
    Function takes  title of node, and rdf notation.
    """
    valid_formats = ["xml", "n3", "ntriples", "trix"]
    default_graph_uri = "http://gstudio.gnowledge.org/rdfstore"
    configString = "/var/tmp/rdfstore"

    # Get the Sleepycat plugin.
    store = plugin.get('IOMemory', Store)('rdfstore')

    # Open previously created store, or create it if it doesn't exist yet
    graph = Graph(store="IOMemory",
               identifier = URIRef(default_graph_uri))
    path = mkdtemp()
    rt = graph.open(path, create=False)
    if rt == NO_STORE:
    #There is no underlying Sleepycat infrastructure, create it
        graph.open(path, create=True)
    else:
        assert rt == VALID_STORE, "The underlying store is corrupt"

    # Now we'll add some triples to the graph & commit the changes
   # rdflib = Namespace('http://sbox.gnowledge.org/gstudio/')
    graph.bind("gstudio", "http://gnowledge.org/")
    exclusion_fields = ["id", "rght", "node_ptr_id", "image", "lft", "_state", "_altnames_cache", "_tags_cache", "nid_ptr_id", "_mptt_cached_fields"]
    node_type=get_nodetype(name)
    if (node_type=='gbobject'):
        node=Gbobject.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='objecttype'):
        node=Objecttype.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='metatype'):
        node=Metatype.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='attributetype'):
        node=Attributetype.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='relationtype'):
        node=Relationtype.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='attribute'):
        node=Attribute.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='complement'):
        node=Complement.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='union'):
        node=Union.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='intersection'):
        node=Intersection.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='expression'):
        node=Expression.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='processtype'):
        node=Processtype.objects.get(title=name)
    elif (node_type=='systemtype'):
        node=Systemtype.objects.get(title=name)

    node_url=node.get_absolute_url()
    site_add= node.sites.all() 
    a = site_add[0] 
    host_name =a.name
    #host_name=name
    link='http://'
    #Concatenating the above variables will give the url address.

    url_add=link+host_name+node_url
    rdflib = Namespace(url_add)
 # node=Objecttype.objects.get(title=name)

    node_dict=node.__dict__

    subject=str(node_dict['id'])
    for key in node_dict:
        if key not in exclusion_fields:
            predicate=str(key)
            pobject=str(node_dict[predicate])
            graph.add((rdflib[subject], rdflib[predicate], Literal(pobject)))

    rdf_code= graph.serialize(format=notation)

    # print out all the triples in the graph
    for subject, predicate, object in graph:
        print subject, predicate, object

    graph.commit()
    print rdf_code
    graph.close()
```

can I directly pass the rdf_code to 4store...if yes then how?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to transform that graph into `ntriples` and send it to `http://yourhost:port/data/GRAPH_URI`. If you do an `HTTP POST` then the triples will be appended to the existing graph represented by `GRAPH_URI`. If you do a HTTP PUT then the current graph will be replaced. If the graph does not exist then it will be created no matter if you `POST` or `PUT`.

Taking this function as example:

```
def assert4s(data,epr,graph,contenttype,flush=False):
    try:
        params = urllib.urlencode({'graph': graph,
                                   'data': data,
                                   'mime-type' : contenttype })
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
        request = urllib2.Request(epr,params)
        request.get_method = lambda: ('PUT' if flush else 'POST')
        url = opener.open(request)
        return url.read()
    except Exception, e:
        raise e
```

If you had the following data:

```
triples = """<a> <b> <c> .
<d> <e> <f> .
"""
```

You can do the following call:

```
assert4s(triples,
         "http://yourhost:port/data/",
         "http://some.org/graph/id",
         "application/x-turtle")
```

**Edit**

My previous answer assumed you were using the 4s-httpd server. You can start the SPARQL server in 4store with the following command `4s-httpd -p PORT kb_name`. Once you have this running, you can use the following services for:

- http://localhost:port/sparql/ to submit queries
- http://localhost:port/data/ to PUT or POST data files.
- http://localhost:port/update/ to submit SPARQL updates queries.

The 4store [SPARQLServer](http://4store.org/trac/wiki/SparqlServer) documentation is quite complete.

Comment: hey thanks so much!
could you please specify this a bit more
        `assert4s(triples,
        ["http://yourhost:port/data/"],   
        ["http://some.org/graph/id"],`

 -is this the home domain of the RDF graph ??/ i have tried "http://example.org" and also my home URI for the RDF, and also the same url as "http://yourhost:port/data". Am i missing something here??  The docs on 4store are too cryptic.

Comment: `http://yourhost:port/data/` it is not the home domain of the RDF data. It is where the 4store http server is listening. `http://some.org/graph/id` is name of the graph and you can basically put whatever you want. See new edit on my answer for further explanation.

Comment: before running the 4Store server when I am executing the code I am getting following error:   `** error:Connection reset by peer **`        and if I run the 4store server and then execute the program then I am getting following error:`** URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>**`

Comment: are you sure you are connecting to the right port ? best thing for you is to email http://groups.google.com/group/4store-support people there is very helpful and respond quite quickly.